# How to change uitableviewcell's custom uilabel using notification with out reloading whole table data in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

I have a tableview 
I set timer in ViewDidLoad() as follows

```
self.timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 10.0, target: self, selector: Selector("fireCellsUpdate"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(self.timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)

func fireCellsUpdate() {

        print("In fireCellsUpdate")
        let notification = NSNotification(name: "CustomCellUpdate", object:UILabel())
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(notification)
    }

and in tableviewcell as follows

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "mycell")
var lbl_uploadTime = UILabel()
lbl_uploadTime.tag = indexPath.row
lbl_uploadTime.text = "3 hours 2 mins"
cell.contentView.addsubView(lbl_uploadTime)
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "updateCountdownLabel:", name: "CustomCellUpdate", object: nil)

}
```

How can I update text for lbl_uploadTime without reloading whole tableview?

Here I reload whole tableview

```
func updateCountdownLabel(notification: NSNotification) {
        println("broadcast received in cell   %@",notification)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

            self.tableview_DiscoverVideos.reloadData()
        })
    }
```

But I want to change only label text without reloading whole tableview. Please help me.

Comment: Well you will need a way to know what row and what section the cell is at. Then call `yourTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath` .

Comment: change the value of particular cell's lbl_uploadTime and reload just cell instead of Whole tableview

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati how can I do that

Comment: @boidkan How can I get section in method func updateCountdownLabel(notification: NSNotification){}?

Comment: which UITableviewcell do you want to reload?

Comment: the lbl_uploadTime label text having Ex: 3 hours and 2 mins then for next minute we have to change to 3 hours 1 min . In this way I have to refresh that label

Comment: how could you know that which cell's label text you want to change? do You Get Index for that cell or anything else?

Comment: I have to pass indexpath row which cell is added a minute ago to that notification

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to subclass `UITableViewCell` and add observer in that cell and then update to that `UILabel` to whatever you need. You should not add observer in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

**Update: improvement**:

Add observers in only custom cells where you need to change Label.

Comment: The issue is that if you add an observer for every cell and all the observers use the same name then then a post will trigger an observer for each cell. So this isn't the best solution.

Comment: Updated my answer. However, NSNotification is not a good way to do this, but as asked in the question, "using-notification", this is my suggestion.